# Is there any equivalent feature to BPMN UserTask available in AWS Step functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, bpmn, camunda, aws-step-functions

We have our old 'Camunda based Spring boot application' which we currently deployed it into kubernetes which is running in an AWS EC2 Instance. This application acts as a **backend for an angular based UI application.**

Now we need to develop a new application similar to the above, which needs to interact with UI.
Our process flow will contain some UserTasks (BPMN) which **will wait until manual interaction performed by human user via angular UI.**

We are evaluating the possibility of using AWS stepfunctions instead of Camunda, if possible.
I googled but unable to find a concrete answer.

Is AWS stepfunctions have any feature similar to BPMN/Camunda's **UserTask** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

====================================

Long answer:

After a whole day of study, I decided to continue with CamundaBPM because of below reasons.

1. AWS step-functions **don't** have an equivalent feature of **UserTask** in BPMN.
   Step functions supports minimal human intervention **via sending emails/messages** by using AWS SQS(simple queue service) and AWS SNS(simple notification service).

Refer this [**link for full example**](https://medium.com/ballerina-techblog/practical-serverless-long-running-workflows-with-human-interactions-using-step-functions-and-dd6fbcb42f29). This manual interaction also based on **'task token'.** So this interaction is limited to basic conversational style.

2. Step-function is **NOT** coming with **in-built database & data management support**, the developer has to take care of designing database schema, creating tables, their relationship etc.

On the other hand, **Camunda is taking care of** creating tables, their relationship, saving & fetching data.

3. **No GUI modeler is available** in step-functions, instead you need to draw workflow in a JSON-like language. This will be very difficult if your workflow becomes complex.

Drawing workflow in Camunda is **just drag-and-drop** using it's modeler.

Comment: Did not understand your last comment - AWS Step Functions also provides drag and drop